# Given a set of primes S, show that no prime in S divides the sum of staggered products of these primes.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

**Definition:**
Given a set of primes $S = \{p_1, p_2\, \cdots, p_n\}$ with $|S| \ge 2$, form the *sum of staggered products* using the following formula:
$$
\sum_{i} \prod_{j \ne i} p_j
$$

**Example:**
If $S = \{2, 3, 5 \}$, then $\sum_{i} \prod_{j \ne i} p_j = 3 \cdot 5 + 2 \cdot 5 + 2 \cdot 3 = 31$

**Question:**

Is it true that no prime in $S$ divides the *sum of staggered products*? i.e. Does $p_k | \sum_{i} \prod_{j \ne i} p_j$ for any $k \in \{1, \cdots, n \}$ ?

**Comments:**
I've done some numerical experiments and it *seems* to be true, but I'm not sure how to go about proving it. I've considered rewriting the *sum of staggered products* as $\sum_{i} \prod_{j} \frac{p_j}{p_i}$, so I could maybe work in modulo $p_k$ and maybe show that $\sum_{i} \frac{1}{p_i} \not\equiv 0$, but I'm not sure how to actually do this. Any suggestions would be helpful.

[This isn't a homework question, but I'd still like it if full answers weren't provided :)]

Comment: Perhaps expressing your sum a little differently would help seeing the answer. $p_n\#$ (read $p$ primorial) is the product of the first $n$ primes. As such, for any particular $n$ it is a constant. Your sum can be expressed $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{p_n\#}{p_i}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. Consider a simpler statement: if $p\mid a$ and $p\mid(a+b)$, then $p\mid b$.

> Each prime in the set $S$ is a factor of each term of the sum except one term. If $p_k$ divided the sum of staggered products, it would also have to divide each term in the sum.

Comment: So from your simpler statement, we would have that given $p | a$, then $p \nmid b$ implies $p \nmid (a + b)$?

Comment: exactly. $\,\!$

Answer (score 2):

Consider your example: each $p$ in $S$ divides all of the sum terms except for one. Can you see why the sum term that $p$ doesn't divide "spoils" the divisibility the sum?

Comment: It definitely seems like the sum term that p doesn't divide turns it into a rational number.. but I wasn't sure if this argument was solid.

Comment: @asfeynman I assume the primes are distinct, or else you could come up with a trivial counterexample (ex. $(2,2)$). The fundamental theorem of arithmetic shows why the bad term can't divide $p$.

Comment: Hmm, so thinking further, since this sum isn't divisible by any $p$, it means that this sum is either another prime not in $S$ or a composite number with a prime not included in $S$.